# Does the PG Ruby Gem use pgpass when setting up PostgreSQL connection?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, database-connection, psql

I'm writing a Ruby script that uses the PG gem to set up a database connection and send files.  I'm structuring it to take variables for the hostname, username, database name, and port.  In a Shell script I've written to manage some companion tasks, I rely on the password stored in `~/.pgpass` instead of having the user enter a password for `psql` because there are a lot of transactions and sometimes entering the password can fail for no apparent reason (and it sucks entering it in 20 times).

Will PG access the same source when a password isn't explicitly provided?  By convention, I've included the password in the file, but since this is being pushed to an internally available repo, I'd prefer not to have that information in my file.  I'm trying to test the functionality now, but was wondering if anyone in the SO community knows the answer to this question.  If PG doesn't access the .pgpass file, is there a way to reference the variable and write it into the file without prompting the user to enter the password?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will use `~/.pgpass` just like any interface based on `libpq`, the C PostgreSQL client library.

However, a good alternative for not having the password in a file is to have it in the [`PGPASSWORD`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) environment variable. If you set this in a script, it will be inherited by every program it calls.

`PGPASSWORD` when set will be used as the password for any `libpq` connection, which means the majority of programs that connect to PostgreSQL.